Bounding Volume Proof Assistant Library
I am interested in learning Lean/Coq/Isabelle etc. and wanted to try to formalize Joseph O'Rourke's Minimum Bounding Box Algorithm. I do not have much experience with proof assistant tools.
Is there a recommendation for a proof-assistant tool to do this in (i.e. that has an extensive computational geometry library of proofs (or even better, a library that has a lot of facts on bounding volumes))? Or am I stuck with just picking a tool and starting from scratch on coming up with all of the definitions and theorems needed to get there?

Possibly related, possibly helpful, but not an answer: A while ago I coded up a Coq implementation of an O(n log n) algorithm for finding the closest pair of points in a plane here

Ask again in 10 years... But seriously, if you are not experienced with formalization, I would recommend doing something easier (much easier) first. For example, prove someting 2-dimensional first. That should give you an idea of what you're up against.
